# How to initialise a lightbox

Tags: javascript, css, html

I tried to use a page on

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

to start with the project. So I took the code an assumed to find out, what I need from the larger page for me. Though, cutting anything away made id not function at all.

What resources are needed (css, js, links)?

I need on several pages a light box and want to load the first picture as soon as the page loads. Tried to build a test page on

http://grillparzerhof.at/magnificversuch/index.html

though there is a light box not at all. It is a very beginners question; please help.

~ Karl

Comment: the website has clear and concise documentation, have you read it?

Comment: Magnific Popup needs jquery library. You forget to add it in your page.

Comment: Please, check your browser console before posting a question.

Comment: Yes, fandressouza, I Reader the really good documentation. Though there seems tu be just a little point in the matter, which is the author assuming that I know. And I do not. Sorry. I am sure to need just a little push…

Answer (score 0):

This is the code on that page in Public Methods you should use to fire the lightbox on page load, this instruction is near the bottom of the Documentation page:

```html
// Open popup immediately. If popup is already opened - it'll just overwite the content (but old options will be kept).
// - first parameter: options object
// - second parameter (optional): index of item to open
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: 'someimage.jpg'
  },
  type: 'image'

  // You may add options here, they're exactly the same as for $.fn.magnificPopup call
  // Note that some settings that rely on click event (like disableOn or midClick) will not work here
}, 0);
```